# how to filter a collection of payloads before collection aggregator

Tags: filter, mule

I receive a collection addresses from a service:

```
[{addressNumber=2386674, addressType=Email, line1=sdfjnfk.de@gmail.com}, {addressNumber=2386690, addressType=Postal, line1=VILLA PALMS NO X}, {addressNumber=1771597, addressType=Physical, line1=P O BOX 56}]
```

I Only want to addresses of addressType = Postal and addressType = Email. and then i want to aggregate the new payload. My current strategy is in a foreach where the payload goes through a filter and then aggregates whats left after the filter. but after the payloads went through the filter it doesn't aggregate. Its as if mule just stops right before the aggregator. when i remove the filter the aggregator works again.

```
    <flow name="prototypingFlow1" doc:name="prototypingFlow1">
    <foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <or-filter doc:name="Or">
            <expression-filter expression="#[payload.addressType == 'Postal']"/>
            <expression-filter expression="#[payload.addressType == 'Email']"/>
        </or-filter>
        <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
    </foreach>
</flow>
```

how can i aggregate payloads after using a filter. or maybe using a filter inside a aggregator? I would like to return this payload with only email and postal addresses

```
    [{addressNumber=2386674, addressType=Email, line1=sdfjnfk.de@gmail.com}, {addressNumber=2386690, addressType=Postal, line1=VILLA PALMS NO X}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use a simple mule groovy component to filter out the data that you don't want, instead of implementing filters and aggregators?

Here is a simple example that will take a JSON string (could of course be left out if a proper collection is available) and filters out everything that is of type "Postal" or "Email".

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper();
def inCollection = slurper.parseText(payload);

def outCollection=[];
for ( a in inCollection ) {
   if(a['addressType'] == 'Postal' || a['addressType'] == 'Email'){
       outCollection.push(a);
   }
} 
return outCollection;
```